# ctrl-enter in the search box open a new tab anymore?

Tags: bug, search

I used to be able to type something in the search box in the top right, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit the search in a new tab.  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> still works to open a new *window* with the search results.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> worked as recently as two weeks ago, I'm almost certain.  I'm using the same computer running the same version of Chromium 51 as I was then.

Is this a bug, or an intentional change?  Or am I doing something wrong?